# MySQL search string in column

Tags: php, mysql

My table name is `Users`. I have a column called `ID` and a `var $id = '123123'`.

I want to find out how many cells in column `ID` equals `'123123'`. So far I have this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE INSTR(ID, '{$id}') > 0 ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

And I want `$result` to be an int.

Comment: Why do you use `INSTR` ? use a simple `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to get a count of all columns whose ID equals `'123123'` **exactly**. You can use this code to do that:

```
$id = '123123';
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE ID = '{$id}'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This return the count of rows selected if I'm not mistaken.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Users WHERE ID = '{$id}'";
```

Comment: Edited my answer based on @sagi 's comment about the WHERE clause. I've double checked the query on one of my tables, this lis should work. If it's not, something else is wrong I guess.